# Only HTTPS connections allowed

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, https

For whatever reason I can only use HTTPS connection to the internet, regardless of the browser.

I'm using Mac Mini with Mountain Lion 10.8.
The problem occurs when TorBrowserBundle is not running, using Safari or Firefox. Maybe Tor is completely innocent, but it's the one that comes to my mind when thinking about secure connections. I just don't know where else to dig deeper.

Is there a possibility that Tor changes network connections to 'HTTPS only' and forgets to reset before closing it?

Is there any other way to reject HTTP connections?

Comment: "Regardless of the browser". What does your setup look like? Do you use the Tor Browser Bundle (TBB)? How do you use other browsers with Tor? What is your OS?

Answer (score 1):

The Tor Browser Bundle ships the plugin [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere). This plugin tries to access many sites via HTTPS. However the plugin works on a list of sites. When a site is not listed or has some weaknesses it is not accessed through HTTPS.

When you use another browser (other than Tor Browser) and this browser has no plugin installed, you are be able to access HTTP as well as HTTPS sites.